# Using dplyr's mutate and case_when to test multiple columns (date intervals)

Tags: r, tidyverse, intervals, dplyr

I have a data set with ~250 columns corresponding to dates. I have created a time-interval using the `interval()` command and I would like to test whether any of the 250 date columns are `%within%` my interval variable, and create a new column of "Y" or "N".

What I have tried (which has not worked) is something along the lines of:

```
date_cols <- names(df[,1:250]) 

df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(test=case_when(date_cols %within% interval ~ "Y",
                        TRUE ~ "N"))
```

And what I would expect this to operate similarly to would be if I were to do

```
df_new <- df %>%
mutate(test=case_when(date_col_1 %within% interval ~ "Y",
                     date_col_2 %within% interval ~ "Y",
                     ...
                     date_col_250 %within% interval ~ "Y",
                     TRUE ~ "N"))
```

Obviously, I do not want to have to type out `case_when()` lines for all 250 columns, but I have yet to find or tidyverse (or really any) solution which works for trying to find if the dates are in the interval.

Any ideas?

Comment: Matt, it really helps when we have a sample of your data, better if that sample shows a little variability. Can you include an unambiguous sample of your data from `dput(head(df))`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably harder to do this in dplyr, since it's effectively a one-liner in base R. Let's take a toy version of your set-up, with an interval and a mini data frame with just two date columns:

```r
library(lubridate)

interval <- interval(as.Date("2020-07-01"), as.Date("2020-07-04"))

df <- data.frame(id   = 1:10,
                 col1 = seq(as.Date("2020-06-30"), by = "1 day", length.out = 10), 
                 col2 = seq(as.Date("2020-06-25"), by = "1 day", length.out = 10))

df
#>    id       col1       col2
#> 1   1 2020-06-30 2020-06-25
#> 2   2 2020-07-01 2020-06-26
#> 3   3 2020-07-02 2020-06-27
#> 4   4 2020-07-03 2020-06-28
#> 5   5 2020-07-04 2020-06-29
#> 6   6 2020-07-05 2020-06-30
#> 7   7 2020-07-06 2020-07-01
#> 8   8 2020-07-07 2020-07-02
#> 9   9 2020-07-08 2020-07-03
#> 10 10 2020-07-09 2020-07-04
```

Now it sounds as if you want a logical column for each existing date column indicating whether its dates were in the interval. You can create these columns as a new data frame like this:

```
data.frame(t(apply(df[date_cols], 1, function(x) as.Date(x) %within% interval)))
#>       X1    X2
#> 1  FALSE FALSE
#> 2   TRUE FALSE
#> 3   TRUE FALSE
#> 4   TRUE FALSE
#> 5   TRUE FALSE
#> 6  FALSE FALSE
#> 7  FALSE  TRUE
#> 8  FALSE  TRUE
#> 9  FALSE  TRUE
#> 10 FALSE  TRUE
```

So if you want to add the columns to your data frame you could do something like:

```
df2 <- data.frame(t(apply(df[date_cols], 1, function(x) as.Date(x) %within% interval)))
df2 <- setNames(df2, paste0(date_cols, "_in_interval"))

cbind(df, df2)
#>    id       col1       col2 col1_in_interval col2_in_interval
#> 1   1 2020-06-30 2020-06-25            FALSE            FALSE
#> 2   2 2020-07-01 2020-06-26             TRUE            FALSE
#> 3   3 2020-07-02 2020-06-27             TRUE            FALSE
#> 4   4 2020-07-03 2020-06-28             TRUE            FALSE
#> 5   5 2020-07-04 2020-06-29             TRUE            FALSE
#> 6   6 2020-07-05 2020-06-30            FALSE            FALSE
#> 7   7 2020-07-06 2020-07-01            FALSE             TRUE
#> 8   8 2020-07-07 2020-07-02            FALSE             TRUE
#> 9   9 2020-07-08 2020-07-03            FALSE             TRUE
#> 10 10 2020-07-09 2020-07-04            FALSE             TRUE
```

Or, using the pipe, your solution would look like this:

```
date_cols <- names(df[1:250])

df[date_cols] %>%
  apply(1, function(x) as.Date(x) %within% interval) %>%
  t() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(paste0(date_cols, "_within_interval")) %>%
  cbind(df, .)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way that rather than having the multiple logical columns for each date column to create a single column which is TRUE if ANY of the logical columns are TRUE and FALSE otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` over `date_cols` to get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values for dates which are within the `interval`. We use `rowSums` to find out if there is any date that lies in the `interval.

Using @Allan Cameron's data :

```
library(lubridate)
date_cols <- 2:3
df$test <- rowSums(sapply(df[date_cols], `%within%`, interval)) > 0
df

#   id       col1       col2  test
#1   1 2020-06-30 2020-06-25 FALSE
#2   2 2020-07-01 2020-06-26  TRUE
#3   3 2020-07-02 2020-06-27  TRUE
#4   4 2020-07-03 2020-06-28  TRUE
#5   5 2020-07-04 2020-06-29  TRUE
#6   6 2020-07-05 2020-06-30 FALSE
#7   7 2020-07-06 2020-07-01  TRUE
#8   8 2020-07-07 2020-07-02  TRUE
#9   9 2020-07-08 2020-07-03  TRUE
#10 10 2020-07-09 2020-07-04  TRUE
```